# Set value to two decimal places

Tags: php

I'd like to get the value of $total_usd to have only 2 decimals only. How do I do that for this code?

```
function cdmb_display_meta_box() {
    // Get

global $post;
    $total_usd = (get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true )) / 0.75;
    $total_usd .= get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_order_total_base_currency', true );

    echo '<p>' . $total_usd . '</p>';
```

}

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
echo '<p>' . number_format(floatval($total_usd), 2) . '</p>';
```

Comment: It worked! Here's variation code for the output. <td><?php echo esc_html( ( empty( $total_usd ) ) ? __( 'N/A', 'wc-usd-display' ) : number_format(floatval($total_usd), 2) ); ?></td>